# Export PDF file executing .R through VBA

Tags: r, vba, pdf, ggplot2

I would like to execute a R code (backend) to plot a graph and export it as a pdf through VBA (which is frontend here).

The VBA code I use is the following :

```
Sub plotHello()
Dim shell As Object
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim path As String
path = """C:\Produits\R\R-3.2.5\bin\R.exe"" CMD BATCH --no-environ --silent --no-restore --no-save C:\R_code\hello.R"
shell.Run (path)
End Sub
```

The thing is : it works with the hello.R file :

```
sink('C:/R_code/hello.txt',append=F,type="output")
cat('Hello World')
sink(NULL)
```

But sink() cannot export graphic output, I should then use the pdf() function

I think the correct syntax is :

```
Library(ggplot2)    
x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y=c(45,78,35,213,65,456)
XY=data.frame(x,y)
g<-ggplot(data=XY,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_line(data=XY,aes(x=x,y=y))
pdf('C:/R_code/hello.pdf')
g
dev.off()
```

Butit doesn't work, also the case with the jpeg() function for instance ... 
BUT it does work when I execute the code in RStudio, the problems seems to be the link between VBA and excel only for pdf function ...
If anyone has a solution, 
many thanks

Comment: Maybe try `print(g)` rather than `g` in the penultimate line of the R script. Also, the script you provided does not load `ggplot2`, so you should have a line with `library(ggplot2)` near the top.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working better .
The thing is the code is working in R but not when I call it from VBA though the link between vba and R is good for it works to export txt with sink()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, Imo was right. The Library has to be imported in the R file even if RStudio is open and the Library has been imported beforehand within RStudio. 
Another remark, if one want to use grid.arrange, this transformation has between the two commands pdf() and dev.off

ex :

```
pdf('C:/R_code/hello.pdf')
grid.arrange(...)
dev.off()
```